# Prestashop Module's CSS Override

Tags: css, overriding, prestashop

I'm new to Prestashop. I want to override the CSS file of a module, say `blockpermanentlinks`.
The official [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors) says that I have to put the new CSS file in
`/themes/my_theme/css/modules/my_module/my_module.css`.

It doesn't work. The line

`<link href="/prestashop/themes/my_theme/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />`

is produced but if I visit that CSS file with my browser a 'Page not found' is displayed.

Any hints?

Comment: Prestashop's version is 1.5.3.1, the latest I found on Prestashop's site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you've answered your own question. The instructions were to put your CSS file in

```
/themes/my_theme/...
```

and you've linked to it at

```
/prestashop/themes/my_theme/...
```

Try

```
<link href="/themes/my_theme/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

It's hard to say anything more without a link to your site.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that Prestashop's base directory is under `/prestashop` folder. I run Prestashop and many other sites on my local machine, for testing. The `/prestashop` part is added automatically by Prestashop.

Comment: Still, it seems like a simple path issue. Use Firebug to try different paths and see what works. Unless your site actually lives at http:yourdomain.com/prestashop/..., my answer should fix the problem.

Comment: A new installation of Prestashop on my local machine directly in /var/www (and not in /var/www/prestashop) fixed the problem. Don't know why. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the CSS file of a module:

go to /themes/{your_theme}/blockpermanentlinks/css/blockpermanentlinks.css

Answer (score 0):

Try this path:

```
/themes/my_theme/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/blockpermanentlinks.css
```

delete **/cache/class_index.php** and make sure to turn on the option from admin as **Force Compilation**, I hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to override only some selectors/properties you can create a custom.css file in:

```
/themes/my_theme/css/autoload/custom.css
```

instead of override the entire css file