# How to change colors in Prestashop 1.5.3 default theme?

Tags: html, css, prestashop

How to change a specific colors in Prestashop 1.5.3 default theme?

[sample1](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/2718/sample1hl.jpg)

[sample2](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/2571/sample2yu.jpg)

[sample3](http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/7856/sample3tl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Use any inspect software in your browser (for example FireBug in Firefox) and you will see CSS classes that need to be changed.

For example for sample 2 image, in global.css find

```
#footer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
color: #FFFFFF;
```

}

Some of them could be in /css folder and other would be in modules folder (to override modules CSS check this link [Prestashop Module's CSS Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343000/prestashop-modules-css-override))

Comment: I find its handy to use any Color Picker utility (for example ColorPix) to find hex color value of target element, then it's easier to define a CSS element that have that value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firefox, then use firebug and check the elements for which you want to change the colors. Firefox will show the css element (class or id), css file name and location and also the line number in the css file. This way it will be very easy to find the css file and css class / id and add your own colors. 
Also firebug provide the feature to add the color directly in it for testing purpose without making any changes in css files, this way it helps to see the css changes effect on the fly.